# Passing a two Dimensional array in javascript function

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw rectangles that represent walls on javascript html canvas. My question here is why doesn't it recognized walls[i].length?

```
canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
context = canvas.getContext('2d')

var boxSize = 40
var wallsCoordinates = [[3,2][3,3],[3,4]]

function drawWalls(walls) {
context.fillStyle = "grey"
for(var i = 0; i < walls.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < walls[i].length; j += 2)
        context.fillRect(walls[i][j] * boxSize, walls[i][j + 1] * boxSize,
            boxSize, boxSize)
    }
}

drawWalls(wallsCoordinates)
```

Comment: It does recognize `walls[i].length`. What exactly is the problem?  Note that your code will go 1 element *beyond* `walls[i]` because of that `j + 1`.

Comment: Typo? `var wallsCoordinates = [[3,2]`,`[3,3],[3,4]]`

Comment: Yes! it was! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a comma in your array.

Change `var wallsCoordinates = [[3,2][3,3],[3,4]]` to `var wallsCoordinates = [[3,2],[3,3],[3,4]]`.

Comment: Oh god! I forgot the comma at first!

Comment: This was such a silly question of me! Only if stack OverFlow allows the author of the  question to delete a question under the approval of the people who answered. Thank you tho!

Comment: If you think that answer helped you, remember to accept it. ;)